# Outputting Search results using Jsoup in java

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to create a Java Program, where I can insert a String into a search bar and then record/print out the results.
This site is: http://maple.fm/khroa
I'm fairly new to JSoup and I've spent several hours just reading the html code regarding that page and have come across variables that could be used to insert the String that I need and get results, although I'm not sure how to exactly do that. Would someone be able to point me to the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the point of JSOUP.

JSOUP can parse a page that is already loaded - **it is not used to interact with a page** (as you want). You could use Selenium to interact with the page (http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and then use JSOUP to parse the loaded page's source code.

In this case, the search results seem to be all loaded when the page load, and the Item Search function only filters the (already existing) results with Javascript.

There are no absolute links you could use to get results to a particular search.